# How to Make an Extension Compatible with Store View Specific ACLs

Tags: magento-enterprise

In Magento Enterprise there is the module `Enterprise_AdminGws` which limits editing rights to specific store views.

How generally is this implemented? i.e. if I create an extension that implements its own data model with data that is stored on store view level, does that mean the limits imposed by `AdminGws` would work out of the box or is it necessary to register my additional resource models with the `Enterprise_AdminGws` extension.

And example could be a blog extension with blog entries and comments: Those have a store-view field and should only be edited by the store-view admin.

*Edit (scope clarification):* It is clear that I have to define my own ACLs in the adminhtml.xml as usual first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While all of the code is provided for you if you're using Magento's built-in structures (customer, sales, etc.) you have to provide your own callback validators for permissions that are specific to your application.

For instance, this observer:

```
<model_save_before>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_admingws>
            <class>enterprise_admingws/observer</class>
            <method>validateModelSaveBefore</method>
        </enterprise_admingws>
    </observers>
</model_save_before>
```

Allows the method `Enterprise_AdminGws_Model_Observer::validateModelSaveBefore` to map to a custom callback method that is derived by the class name. This method is defined in `Models.php`, which has some bootstrap code to determine if the save privileges exist for a particular role.

The callback will either `throw` or return void. Its purpose is to validate only. Add in your own callbacks by extending `Enterprise_AdminGws_Model_Models`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must declare the acl in the adminhtml.config as well (since it's in the title).  Something like

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <moduleName>
                                        <title>moduleName Section</title>
                                    </moduleName>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                    <report>
                        <children>
                            <salesroot>
                                <children>
                                    <moduleName_settlement_reports translate="title">
                                        <title>Settlement Reports</title>
                                        <children>
                                            <view translate="title">
                                                <title>View</title>
                                            </view>
                                            <fetch translate="title">
                                                <title>Fetch</title>
                                            </fetch>
                                        </children>
                                    </moduleName_settlement_reports>
                                </children>
                            </salesroot>
                        </children>
                    </report>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Is what I'm using and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Did you test this with AdminGWS ? i.e. did you create several roles with permissions on different stores and where not able to see that report on another store?  I have edited my question - it is not about the standard ACL definition.

Comment: No, I didn't use that module here, but I believe you must still declare it so use it. I see you edited the question to reflect this.  Don't know why I got down voted for it.

Comment: Just feel free to update you answer according to the edited question :-) no offense ... happy to vote up

Comment: FYI your answer only deals with standard ACL definition. OP is asking about the corresponding check via PHP for admin user scope restrictions specific to Enterprise Edition.